# Max Value with unique values in more than one column

Tags: sql-server

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

Using T-SQL/SQL-Server:

I have unique values in more than one column but want to select the max version based on one particular column.

Dataset:

Example

```
ID | Name| Version | Code
------------------------
1  | Car  | 3       | NULL
1  | Car  | 2       | 1000
1  | Car  | 1       | 2000
```

Target status:  I want my query to only select the row with the highest version value.  Running a MAX on the version column pulls all three because of the distinct values in the 'Code' column:

```
     SELECT  ID
            ,Name
            ,MAX(Version)
            ,Code
       FROM Table
       GROUP BY ID, Name, Code
```

The net result is that I get all three entries as per the data set due to the unique values in the Code column, but I only want the top row (Version 3).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the row with the highest version as 1 query and use another outer query to pull out all the fields for that row. Like so:

```
   SELECT t.ID, t.Name, GRP.Version, t.Code
   FROM (
     SELECT  ID
          ,Name
          ,MAX(Version) as Version
     FROM Table
     GROUP BY ID, Name
   ) GRP
   INNER JOIN Table t on GRP.ID = t.ID and GRP.Name = t.Name and GRP.Version = t.Version
```

Comment: Thanks HashPi, this was the most effective solution (as I have a larger dataset than just those three rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use row_number() to do this kind of logic, for example like this:

```
select ID, Name, Version, Code
from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by Version desc) as RN 
  from Table1
) X where RN = 1
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bd71/2)

Comment: And if you want highest version per ID, you can add "partition by ID" to the row_number

Answer (score 0):

add the [top](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) statment to force the return of a single row. Also add the order by notation

```
SELECT top 1 ID
        ,Name
        ,MAX(Version)
        ,Code
   FROM Table
   GROUP BY ID, Name, Code
   order by max(version) desc
```